# How to enable autoscrolling to bottom for wx.html.HtmlWindow

Tags: python, wxpython, wxhtmlwindow

I am using wxPython and want my `HtmlWindow` to scroll down automatically after adding new content. I am using it as a log window inside my app. Unfortunately, I am struggling to get it working. Here is my sample with lacks the functionality:

```py
import wx
import wx.html


class GUI(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self, -1, pos=(0, 0), size=(50, 50))
        msg = '<pre>FOO</pre>'
        for i in range(10):
            self.html.AppendToPage(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = GUI(parent=None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I want the scrollbar showing the stack of "Foos" to be at the bottom instead of staying on top so that the latest logging content is shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably `wx.html.HtmlWindow` is the wrong tool to use.

You'd have to insert `Anchors` and then leap to each `Anchor`.

For a log, it's better to use a `wx.TextCtrl` e.g.

```
import wx
import time

class GUI(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(600, 480),
                          style=wx.TE_MULTILINE| wx.TE_READONLY| wx.VSCROLL)
        # set initial position at the start
        self.log.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        self.Show()
        
        msg = 'FOO\n'
        for i in range(50):
            self.log.write(msg)
            wx.GetApp().Yield()
            time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = GUI(parent=None)
    app.MainLoop()
```